# AOP for annotation is not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have myannotation and whenever my method(which has myannotation) is executed then AOP should be called but which is not working in my spring boot controller.But which is working for methods which has other annotations.Please help me to understand about what happens.

**Update: MyAnnotation**

```
 @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR })
    public @interface MyAnnotation {
    }

@Aspect
@Component
public class AnnotationAspect {
    private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD1 = "@annotation(com.somepackage.MyAnnotation)";


    @Around(POINTCUT_METHOD1)
    public Object weaveJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        try {
            System.out.println("Beforeee " + joinPoint);
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Afterrr " + joinPoint);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Scenario 1:(Working)**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
public class ArticleController {

    @GetMapping("article/{id}")
    @MyAnnotation // here it is
    public ResponseEntity<String> getArticleById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) 
 {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(dummyMethod(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public String dummyMethod() {
        System.out.println("Dummy method with MyAnnotation");
        return "HelloWorld!";
    }
}
```

**Log:(Working)**

```
Beforeee execution(ResponseEntity com.mypackage.getArticleById(Integer))
Dummy method with MyAnnotation
Afterrr execution(ResponseEntity com.mypackage.getArticleById(Integer))
```

**Scenario 2:(Not Working)**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
public class ArticleController {

    @GetMapping("article/{id}")     
    public ResponseEntity<String> getArticleById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) 
 {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(dummyMethod(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @MyAnnotation //here it is
    public String dummyMethod() {
        System.out.println("Dummy method with MyAnnotation");
        return "HelloWorld!";
    }
}
```

Log:(Not Working)

```
Dummy method with MyAnnotation
```

**Scenario 3: (Not Working)**

```
@Service
public class ArticleService {
@MyAnnotation //here it is
public String dummyMethod() {
            System.out.println("Dummy method with MyAnnotation");
            return "HelloWorld!";
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the source code for `@MyAnnotation`

Comment: @Prashant added thanks

Comment: @sunleo have you fixed this issue. Can you explain bit here.

Answer (score 5):

It might not work because you call dummyMethod() from the same class. Try moving dummyMethod() to another service class. The reason is that calls within the same class does not go though the Spring proxy. The call to getArticleById() is proxied and will be handled by AOP but dummyMethod() might as well be a private method.

Comment: Even in the service class, it is not working., pls check scenario 3

Comment: Can you show code handling the AOP pointcuts? I assume you have something like `@Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation )")`

Comment: Try to do `return joinPoint.proceed()` and don't return `null`.

Comment: no use even I removed return type Object from the method.

Comment: I think you need the return type. 
Try `@Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation) || execution(public * @MyAnnotation *.*(..)))")`